# SQL cannot execute on live server

Tags: php

I am trying to exectute the following on the live server but it does not execute. On the local host everything is fine. I am able to execute other sql on the live server tho

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");

if(isset($_POST['username'])&& isset($_POST['password']) ){
    $username =$_POST['username'];
    $password =  md5($_POST['password']);
    if ($mysqli) {
        /* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
        if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select acc.accountId, acc.firstname, prof.imagename      from accounts acc inner join profilepicture prof on prof.accountId=acc.accountId where acc.emailAddress=(?) and acc.password=(?)"))) {
             echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
        }
        /* Prepared statement, stage 2: bind and execute */
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username,$password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if(!empty($row)){
            `enter code here`
            `enter code here`// STATEMENTS TO EXECUTE IF DETAILS EXISTS
        }
```

Comment: You're not closing correctly the last if and the second one, are you? You're missing **two** bracket (`}`) from what I see. Did you forget to parse it or..? Also, I hope that you **deleted the username and password for posting here, else it is not working because you're not logging into your database.**

Comment: I have just copied and pasted a pie of the code. I cannot see anything wrong with the statement. I can execute other sql statements  using the same connection object. It is only this one which is not working

Answer (score 0):

This could be the reason:  You are logging into mysql with no default database, no username and no password

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "", "", "");
```

should be something like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
```

Read this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Answer (score 0):

In the live server or cpanel.. go to mysql section create the database and user and password... and give that user the permission to edit update and delete.. then in the

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "", "", "");

add all the three the username password and database name..then.. it will work fine.. 
Hope it works

Comment: Hi i have just removed those parameters from the question for security reasons